# How does std::invoke(C++1z) work?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

```
namespace detail {
template <class F, class... Args>
inline auto INVOKE(F&& f, Args&&... args) ->
    decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
      return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <class Base, class T, class Derived>
inline auto INVOKE(T Base::*pmd, Derived&& ref) ->
    decltype(std::forward<Derived>(ref).*pmd) {
      return std::forward<Derived>(ref).*pmd;
}

template <class PMD, class Pointer>
inline auto INVOKE(PMD pmd, Pointer&& ptr) ->
    decltype((*std::forward<Pointer>(ptr)).*pmd) {
      return (*std::forward<Pointer>(ptr)).*pmd;
}

template <class Base, class T, class Derived, class... Args>
inline auto INVOKE(T Base::*pmf, Derived&& ref, Args&&... args) ->
    decltype((std::forward<Derived>(ref).*pmf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
      return (std::forward<Derived>(ref).*pmf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <class PMF, class Pointer, class... Args>
inline auto INVOKE(PMF pmf, Pointer&& ptr, Args&&... args) ->
    decltype(((*std::forward<Pointer>(ptr)).*pmf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
      return ((*std::forward<Pointer>(ptr)).*pmf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
} // namespace detail

template< class F, class... ArgTypes>
decltype(auto) invoke(F&& f, ArgTypes&&... args) {
    return detail::INVOKE(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...);
}
```

I saw the implementation above from here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke

Then I wonder how the compilers match the exact version required. Does SFINAE work on trailing return type?

Comment: Note that this implementation is somewhat broken, since it accepts some constructs that are invalid according to the standard.

Comment: @T.C. You mean PMF or PMD ?

Comment: @T.C. could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @melak47 http://en.cppreference.com/w/Talk:cpp/utility/functional/invoke#Problems_with_the_possible_implementation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does SFINAE work on tailing return type?

Yes. The trailing return type syntax doesn't enable any new functionality, it merely makes it easier to write some cases of return types that depend on parameter types.

```
template <class F, class... Args>
inline auto INVOKE(F&& f, Args&&... args) ->
   decltype(std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...) { ... }
```

could have equivalently been written as

```
template <class F, class... Args>
inline decltype(std::forward<F>(std::declval<F&>())(std::forward<Args>(std::declval<Args&>())...))
INVOKE(F&& f, Args&&... args) { ... }
```

for instance, and the same for all the others. That could be simplified, but even if you simplify it, the fact that the return type cannot use the same syntax as the `return` expression makes it hard to follow what's going on. Hence the new syntax.

The only time SFINAE doesn't work is for deduced return types. They also use `auto`, but it's not the `auto` keyword by itself that disables SFINAE.

Comment: Thanks! BTW I just noticed my awkward spelling from you quote :-(

Comment: @iDingDong Don't worry about it, it actually works both as "tailing" and as "trailing". :)

Comment: And I still wonder is there any C++1z core language feature required for SFINAE to work on this case?

Comment: @iDingDong The trailing return type syntax was added in C++11, and ever since that first version, it already allowed for SFINAE to work. That's what I tried to convey in my answer. If you can tell in what way my answer is not clear on that, I'll try to edit it.